# Write the proper query

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've got a struct with enum and would like to write a LINQ query to get all of the products which is in the category: gaming" and has a stock of 10+.

This is how my code looks like now:

```
    public enum Kind {console, game, hardware}
    public struct Products
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Price { get; set; }
        public int Stock { get; set; }
        public Kind Prod;

        public Products(int id, string name, int price,int stock, Kind prod)
        {
            Id = id;
            Name = name;
            Price = price;
            Stock = stock;
            Prod = prod;
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List < Products > test= new List<Products>();
        test.Add(new Products(123, "Xbox", 300, 2, Kind.console));
        test.Add(new Products(234, "Motherboard", 100, 11, Kind.hardware));
        test.Add(new Products(345, "Forza", 29, 20, Kind.game));
        test.Add(new Products(456, "AC", 50, 5, Kind.game));

        var x = from t in test
                 where t.Stock > 10
                 select t;
        foreach(var f in x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(f.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Can you guys help me what should be the right query?

Comment: where t.Prod == Kind.game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linq `Where` clause with `&&` operator,

Using method syntax:

```
var result = test.Where(x => x.Stock > 10 && x.Prod == Kind.game);
```

Using query syntax,

```
var result = from t in test
       where t.Stock > 10 && t.Prod == Kind.game
       select t;       //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ This was missing
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following LINQ,

```
var res = test.Where(x => x.Prod == Kind.game && x.Stock > 10);

foreach (var item in res) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
}
```